# where to find the source of dbpedia data

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, wikimedia-dumps

I would like to compare dbpedia 2015-10 dataset (http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-10) with the original wikipedia source. The link (http://services-resources/datasets/dataset-2015-10/dump-dates-dbpedia-2015-10) they provided is not accessible at the moment. Doe anyone know how to get the original data?

Comment: October 2015 dumps [are still available from Wikimedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20151002/), and they also have [archive.org mirror](https://archive.org/details/enwiki-20151002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you are trying to access is incorrect. The correct URL is:

- http://wiki.dbpedia.org/services-resources/datasets/dataset-2015-10/dump-dates-dbpedia-2015-10

It lists Wikipedia dump dates. It is 2015-10-02 for most Wikipedia languages.

The dumps are available [from Wikipedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20151002/) like @svick wrote in a commment.